# React Update validation with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am reusing the same form for the creation and update of the record. When doing this, it works fine for the creation as I need a password, but for the update I don't need the password as the user may just want to modify his information and leave the password as is. So, what are the react hook form parameters that I have to set up to make the field password optional when the form is included from the update page?

```
  <TextField
    {...register("password", {
        required: "You must specify a password",
        minLength: {
          value: 8,
          message: "Password must have at least 8 characters"
        }
    })}
    name="password"
    autoComplete={"New password"}
    error={errors.password ? true : false}
    helperText={errors.password ? errors.password.message : ""}
    label="Password"
    type="password"
  />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a easy way. Separate this part as an object.

```
var pwdRule = {
            required: "You must specify a password",
            minLength: {
              value: 8,
              message: "Password must have at least 8 characters"
            }
```

Customize the `pwdRule` using `state` in the way you want like this.

```
var pwdRule = { ...rule1 here} // rule when it is not required.
if (...required) {
    pwdRule = {
       ...pwdRule,
       //new rule here like required, minLength
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
<TextField
    {...register("password", pwdRule)}
...
```